# How to convert an image to a 0-255 grey scale image

Tags: java, image-processing, grayscale

### I want to convert an image to a gray scale image where pixel intensities are **between *0-255***.

I was able to convert images to a gray scale images with the following Java method.

```
public void ConvertToGrayScale(BufferedImage bufImage, int ImgWidth, int ImgHeight) {

    for (int w = 0; w < ImgWidth; w++) {
        for (int h = 0; h < ImgHeight; h++) {

            Color color = new Color(bufImage.getRGB(w, h));
            int ColAvgVal = ((color.getRed() + color.getGreen() + color.getBlue()) / 3);
            Color avg = new Color(ColAvgVal, ColAvgVal, ColAvgVal);

            bufImage.setRGB(w, h, avg.getRGB());

            System.out.println(avg.getRGB());
        }
    }
}
```

"System.out.println(avg.getRGB());"  is used to see the pixel intensities but the **all the grey levels are minus values and not between 0-255**.

Am I doing it wrong ? How would I convert an image to a gray scale image where pixel intensities are **between 0-255**.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`color.getRGB()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB()) does not return a value from 0..255, it returns an integer composited of your red, green and blue values, including the Alpha value. Presumably, this alpha value is `0xFF`, which makes *any* combined color end up as `0xFFrrggbb`, or, as you got, a huge negative number when written in decimals.

To see the "gray" level assigned, just check `ColAvgVal`.

Note that a better formula to convert between RGB and grayscale is to use the [PAL/NTSC conversion](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale):

```
gray = 0.299 * red + 0.587 * green + 0.114 * blue
```

because "full blue" should be darker in grayscale than "full red" and "full green".

---

Note: if you use this formula directly, watch out for *floating point rounding errors*. In theory, it should not return a value outside of `0..255` for `gray`; in practice, *it will*. So test and clamp the result.

Another option which does not require testing-and-clamping per pixel, is to use an integer-only version:

```
gray = (299 * red + 587 * green + 114 * blue)/1000;
```

which should work with only a very small rounding error.

Comment: Another option would be: `gray = (77*red + 150*green + 29*blue) >> 8;`.  Bitshifting to the right by 8 is equivalent to dividing by 256, and `77/256 = 0.299, 150/256 = 0.587` and `29/256 = 0.114`.  This computes the SMPTE standard for converting to grayscale like you have said, but it avoids division all together.  Still, great workaround on your integer-only version!

Comment: @Jongware
Thanks for the reply

When I printed the "ColAvgVal" values I was able to see the grey levels from 0..255.

I tried assigning the "ColAvgVal" to the 

    bufImage.setRGB(w, h, ColAvgVal);

and I got a blue colored image. Since i want to get a gray scale image from grey levels 0..255 how would I get it?

Thanks

Comment: @user3347358 - You need to set **all** colour components to be the same value for it to look grayscale.  Set `gray` to `ColAvgVal` and make a new colour out of it like: `Color avg = new Color(ColAvgVal, ColAvgVal, ColAvgVal);`, then do `bufImage.setRGB(w, h, avg.getRGB());`

Comment: @rayryeng

Thanks for the reply

I have already done that and I have mentioned that in the code segment of the method.

but am I getting the 0..255 grey level image by doing that?

How would I see the assigned grey levels of the "bufImage" after the

bufImage.setRGB(w, h, avg.getRGB());  operation

Thanks

Comment: @user3347358 - That was already calculated by `ColAvgVal`.  The red, green and blue values for a grayscale image are **all** the same, so all you need to do is print out `ColAvgVal`.  This value would be the same for all RGB components.  However, if you want to be technical, do `avg.getRed(); avg.getGreen(); avg.getBlue();`.  Curious to know why you're asking this when you have seen an equivalent statement done earlier in the loop.

Comment: @rayryeng

Imagine that I want to see the grey levels (from 0..255) of the "bufImage" (the grayscaled image) in another place after doing the 

bufImage.setRGB(w, h, avg.getRGB());  operation

How would I see the grey levels?

Thanks

Comment: @user3347358 - Why don't you save the image to file and load it up on an image viewer?  `File outputfile = new File("grayScale.png"); ImageIO.write(bufImage, "png", outputfile);`  Put that as the last statement in that method before you return.

Comment: @rayryeng

After I saved the image I want to access and print its grey levels (0..255)
How would I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Do this: `System.out.println(ColAvgVal);`, in the loop, which is what *I have already told you before*.  I'm going to stop flooding the comments of Jongware's post and I'm going to leave you with that.  Good luck!

Answer (score -3):

You can check [this](http://zerocool.is-a-geek.net/java-color-image-to-grayscale-conversion-algorithm/) . I hope it can help you.

You can check some differents methods like:

```
// The average grayscale method
private static BufferedImage avg(BufferedImage original) {

int alpha, red, green, blue;
int newPixel;

BufferedImage avg_gray = new BufferedImage(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), original.getType());
int[] avgLUT = new int[766];
for(int i=0; i<avgLUT.length; i++)
    avgLUT[i] = (int) (i / 3);

for(int i=0; i<original.getWidth(); i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<original.getHeight(); j++) {

        // Get pixels by R, G, B
        alpha = new Color(original.getRGB(i, j)).getAlpha();
        red = new Color(original.getRGB(i, j)).getRed();
        green = new Color(original.getRGB(i, j)).getGreen();
        blue = new Color(original.getRGB(i, j)).getBlue();

        newPixel = red + green + blue;
        newPixel = avgLUT[newPixel];
        // Return back to original format
        newPixel = colorToRGB(alpha, newPixel, newPixel, newPixel);

        // Write pixels into image
        avg_gray.setRGB(i, j, newPixel);

    }
}

return avg_gray;

}
```

Comment: This does perform grayscale conversion, but you provided no explanation as to why this works.  Also, the `avgLUT` calculation is absolutely unnecessary.  All you're doing is adding up the intensities of each colour channel, then using the LUT to see where this corresponds, which just outputs the sum and divides by 3, which is what the OP already has.  As such, I don't understand the purpose of this post.